# What's different between pronouncing of these words: Get and Gem?

Tags: pronunciation

I know that the *"Ge"* sound is pronounced as *J* in the English language.
For Example: **Gem**.

But the pronunciation of "Get" is not like that.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: "Get" is simply an exception. Wiktionary has a list of such exceptions: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_English_words_where_G_is_pronounced_exceptionally In most cases, the reason for "g" being pronounced with one sound or the other is etymology, as described in this related post on this site: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204231/should-g-followed-by-e-and-i-be-pronounced-with-a-soft-or-hard-g?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: They're two different words.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is:

**g + e, i, y → /ʤ/**

gem /ʤem/

gin /ʤIn/

gel /ʤel/

gene /ʤi:n/

**g + other letters → /g/**

gas /gæz/

bag /bæg/

glad /glæd/

egg /eg/

**Exceptions are:**

give /gIv/, get /get/, girl /gɜ:l/, gift /gIft/, giggle /gIgl/, etc.

**‘gu’ + vowel → /g/:**

guess, guest, guild, guile, guilt, guinea-pig, disguise.

**‘dge’ → /ʤ/:**

edge, bridge, budget, badge, budge, budgie, wedge.

Source: Zolina, Koltakova, and Khakhanova, *English for Beginners*, Voronezh State University, 2007.

The link to the post explaining the etymological reasons for the differences has been included in comments above, and I am copying it here for convenience:

[Should 'g' followed by 'e' and 'i' be pronounced with a soft or hard g?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204231/should-g-followed-by-e-and-i-be-pronounced-with-a-soft-or-hard-g)